# Right side overlay panel Solution

Tags: modal-dialogs

quickie,

I want to create a right-hand side sliding overlay panel for my drupal site.  I have been googling and testing solutions for hours. The exact effect that I want can be found [here.](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/panel/)  The jQuery Mobile overlay panel.

Of course, this script is not working with drupal and bootstrap 3 theme.

Question(s):  Does anyone know a way to make this script work with drupal 7 and bootstrap 3?

The closest substitute that I can find is the Mobile Menu Module (MMenu) module, but it appears to be for navigation purposes only.  I need to add a FAQ with animated expanding divs.  The documentation is unclear if this possible with MMenu.  Can anyone tell me if it is possible?

If I am barking up the wrong tree with jQuery Panel and MMenu is there a better solution? Simple, right hand side overlay panel.

Much appreciate, any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in owning the silliness, when you're being silly.  I answered my own question in the process of posting the question.

Using MMenu module, I simply took my animated divs and put them in a block and loaded the block as content for mmenu.  The js scripts work and the content looks great, only one last hurdle.  But I will do that is an actual question if I can't find a solution.